# Cycle largest size for the value $a^p \pmod k$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a question.

If you can prove what may be the largest size for the cycle $a^p \pmod k$ where $a$, $p$ and $k$ are of course natural numbers?

I found on the Internet but quite specific cases (eg. For bases $a = 10$). I need a general solution.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Largest with what fixed ? $a$, $k$ ?

Comment: Your question is connected to Euler totient function $\phi$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function

Comment: Well, larges cycle for $gcd(a, k) = 1$ is $k-1$?

Comment: No, for example $a=31$ and $k=80$ $gcd(31, 80) = 1$ but cycle is ${1, 31, 1, 31 ...}$ (size is $2$).

Comment: Probably sometimes for $k = prime$, is a cycle size = $k -1$. The question is if $k$ is not a prime number? Then what?

Comment: $\LaTeX$ hint:  to get the mod k to come out, use \pmod k.  For multicharacter moduli, you need braces, so \pmod {12} gives $\pmod {12}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the 
[Multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) for integers modulo $k$ or for [general groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_%28group_theory%29).
For example you have $\mathrm{ord}_{80}(31)=2$. As @JeanMarie has written the order is related to the Euler totient function. In fact 
$\mathrm{ord}_k(a)$ always divides $\varphi(k)$.

We can do even better: $\,\mathrm{ord}_k(a)$ always divides the
[Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) $\lambda(k).\,$  And because $\lambda(80)= 4$ the maximum period length for $k=80$ is $4,\,$ this is achieved for
example with $a=3.$

$$3^2\equiv 9\pmod{80},\quad 3^3\equiv 27\pmod{80},\quad 3^4 \equiv 81 \equiv 1 \pmod{80}$$

Comment: Thank you, You can give proof that $ord_k(a)$ always divides $φ(k)$?

Comment: This follows from the fact that $\mathrm{ord}_k(a)\;$ is the order of the sub-group generated by $a;$  and this divides the group order $\mathbb{Z}_k^{*}=\varphi(k)$ (see the Wiki group ref, keyword **Lagrange theorem**)

Comment: The modern form of the Chinese Remainder Theorem gives you a way to compute the answer to your question directly for any n.